# Excel/Google sheets - duplicating array and extending by value from different array

Tags: excel, google-sheets, join, filter, textjoin

I have some problem with extending some array by values. The easiest way to explain will be show some example, so:

```
A       B       C
==================
A       11      A
B       22      B
C       33      C
                11
                A
                B
                C
                22
                A
                B
                C
                33
```

Of course I can do sth like below:

```
=({A1:A3;B1;A1:A3;B2;A1:A3;B3})
```

But it's not flexible at all.

The main problem is that I want to filter some table by value:

```
A       B       filter key
==================
A       11      11
B       11      33
B       33      
B       33      
C       33
F       44
G       55
```

So I want to get all A column filtered by filter key, but I want also sum of results.
So in above example filtering by 11 is A,B by 33 is B, C.
Final result should be
ABBC

And yeah, this is possible to do like below:

```
=({UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A10;B1:B10=C1));UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A10;B1:B10=C2))})
```

Do you have any idea?

Have a nice Sunday!

**Update:**

If someone will look for solution:

```
=FILTER(INDEX(UNIQUE(A:B);;1);REGEXMATCH(INDEX(UNIQUE(A:B);;2)&""; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; ""&C:C)))
```

Separated A and B columns (so it can be for instance columns A and Z or A from sheet_A, B from sheet_B):

```
=FILTER(INDEX(UNIQUE(UNIQUE({A:A\B:B}));;1);REGEXMATCH(INDEX(UNIQUE({A:A\B:B});;2)&""; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; ""&C:C)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(SPLIT(JOIN("×", TEXTJOIN("×", 1, A2:A)&"×"&FILTER(B2:B, B2:B<>"")), "×")))
```

[image]

```
=FILTER(A2:A, REGEXMATCH(B2:B&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C&"")))
```

[image]

### update:

```
=FILTER(INDEX(UNIQUE(A:B);;1);
 REGEXMATCH(INDEX(UNIQUE(A:B);;2)&""; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; ""&C:C)))
```

[image]

Comment: The formula is almost ok, The result should be unique from first filtering and unique from second filtering:
1. AB 2. BC
I have made mistake in my example formula - it should be:
=({UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A10;B1:B10=C1));UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A10;B1:B10=C2))})

Comment: @tomm in that case use: `=({UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A;B1:B=C1));UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A;B1:B=C2))})`

Comment: Yeah I know it's working ^^
But It's not flexible at all and its the reason why I'm asking

Comment: @tomm you mean that C column part referencing?

Comment: I mean whole "UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A;B1:B=CX))" part have to be duplicated.
If the CX have 10 or more elements the formula will be really long.

Comment: @tomm answer updated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241986/discussion-between-tomm-and-player0).